# Commutative matrices with zero product

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be real matrices (dimension $n \times n$) such that $AB=BA=0$.

So we have for them that columns of $B$ are in nullspace of $A$, and columns of $A$ are in nullspace of $B$. The same can be said about matrices $A^T$  and $B^T$.

Can we deduce something from these equations also  about relation $A^T$ and $B$ ?

Comment: Do you want to show $A^T B = 0$ as well?

Comment: @gerw If possible why not?  (under what conditions ?) Does exist also some relation between eigenspaces of $A^T$ and $B$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not (but "relation" is a bit vague). Consider
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ 
B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}. $$
Then $AB=BA=0$, but $A^TB\ne0$.

Comment: Convincing example for a general case ... when $A^TB$ would be equal 0? Only for symmetric matrices?

Comment: No, it is very easy to get all products equal to zero if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}A_0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&B_0\end{bmatrix}, $$ and you are free to choose  $A_0$ and $B_0$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is what you are looking for, but $AB=0$ says that the space generated by the columns of $A^T$ is orthogonal to the space generated by the columns of $B$, while $BA=0$ says that the space generated by the rows of $A^T$ (in other words by the columns of $A$, but you wanted to consider $A^T$) is orthogonal to the space generated by the rows of $B$.

Comment: Yes, I have known that, I was searching for less known facts for example arising from the decomposition of $A$ into symmetric and skew-symmetric part and then $AB=0$ gives $sym(A)B=-skew(A)B$ but it's hard to see what following exact implications are from that..